# Передать строку PHP в Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с полем `name`

Далее я проверяю поле и вывожу текст ошибки в переменную `$errorName` по очереди с помощью функции `array_shift()`.

```
$errorName = [];

if ($post['name'] == "") {
    $errorName[] = "Это поле обязательно к заполнению";
}

if (strlen($post['name']) < 1) {
    $errorName[] = "Минимальная длина Имени 2 символа";
}

if (strlen($post['name']) > 16) {
    $errorName[] = "Максимальная длина имени 16 символов";
}

if (!empty($errorName)) {
    echo array_shift($errorName);
}
```

Как передать переменную `$errorName` в Javascript если `$errorName` не пустой массив?

Comment: Можно так var errors = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($errorName) ?>')
Можно так var error = '<?= array_shift($errorName) ?>'

Comment: можно ли другим способом не передавая явную переменную php в javascript?

Comment: Через ajax слать запросы, оборачивая все в json, либо использовать перезагрузку страницы и обходиться читым php(ошибки хранить в сессии)

Comment: по другому никак